# Trigger.io App fails Application Loader verification, not respecting minimum os version and cannot verify icon file

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I'm using the latest version of Trigger.io and have my mobile application configured to require iOS 5.0 or higher, and I've got all the icons loaded in the config.json file, e.g:

```
"modules": {
    …
    "icons": {
        "android": {
            "36": "path/to/ICON_36sq.png",
            "48": "path/to/ICON_48sq.png",
            "72": "path/to/ICON_72sq.png"
        },
        "ios": {
            "57": "path/to/ICON_57sq.png",
            "72": "path/to/ICON_72sq.png",
            "114": "path/to/ICON_144sq.png",
            "512": "path/to/ICON_512sq.png",
            "prerendered": true
        }
    },
    …
```

However, when trying to deploy the application to the App Store using the Application Loader, I get the following error:

`iPhone/iPod Touch: Info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found. You must define CFBindleIcons, CFBundleIconFiles, CFBundleIconFile, or provide a default Icon.png that us 57x57.`

[image: Application Loader Error]

The icon file does exist and is correctly configured for my app, so it's not a issue of the file not existing. It also works correctly on the simulator and my development device, just not when releasing to the app store.

Any help is appreciated.

**POSSIBLE CAUSE**: If I dig into the IPA and look at the Plist.info file in the resulting package created by trigger.io, the `MinimumOSVersion` is set to `4.3`, and not respecting what I have in my `config.json` file (minimum version I've set to is `iOS 5.0`).

---

**After more research, I found that I can deploy the app successfully using v1.4.36 and below. Looks like the refactor in v1.4.37 has broken the Minimum OS Requirements again!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the Trigger.io platform: we deployed a fix in v1.4.44 - see https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/release_notes.html

There are currently two ways to define custom icon file names in an iOS app. After recreating an Xcode project we use internally, the newly generated `Info.plist` only conformed to the new style, which causes Application Loader problems.

v1.4.44 restored the old-style icons configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use relative paths from the 'src' directory rather than assuming a baseUrl. So use "path/to/ICON_36sq.png" not "/path/to/ICON_36sq.png"

Comment: Tried that already. The icons are relative to the `src` directory anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at "development/ios/build_steps/icons.json" you'll see something like that.

```
[
{
    "do": {
        "copy_file_from_src": {
            "filename": "{{plugins.icons.config.ios.57}}",
            "dest": "normal.png"
        }
    }
},
{
    "do": {
        "copy_file_from_src": {
            "filename": "{{plugins.icons.config.ios.72}}",
            "dest": "ipad.png"
        }
    }
},
{
    "do": {
        "copy_file_from_src": {
            "filename": "{{plugins.icons.config.ios.114}}",
            "dest": "retina.png"
        }
    }
},
{
    "do": {
        "copy_file_from_src": {
            "filename": "{{plugins.icons.config.ios.144}}",
            "dest": "ipad-retina.png"
        }
    }
},
{
    "do": {
        "icons_handle_prerendered": {}
    }
}
```

]

As shown above, the build is copying the 57px icon in your configuration to "normal.png" and the 72px to "ipad.png", but for some reason the Application Loader is not recognizing the CFBundleIconFiles entry in the Info.plist.

I solved my problem using a [postbuild hook](https://trigger.io/docs/current/tools/hooks.html) to copy the 57px icon to the expected default name "Icon.png" and the 72px icon to "Icon-72.png" (the file names are case sensitive). The files have to be copied to the "development/ios/device-ios.app/" folder.